# Function with other function as argument

Tags: maxima

Please, tell me how use functions in Maxima?
I tried this

```
function(g, u):= (print(g(0)), print(u));
function(x^2, 10);
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to evaluate the first argument with a specific value of the second argument. So maybe you want `ev(g, x=0)` instead of `g(0)`.

(`g(0)` works only if `g` is the name of a function or a lambda expression, i.e., an unnamed function.)

Maybe you can explain in more detail what you want to accomplish.

Comment: i need write a function which takes monomial (such as (x+5)^30 or (x+x^2+1)^20 and etc) and one digit ( it is power of 'x')

for example
function((x^2+5x+1)^20, 1);
and the function return me 100, because (x^2+5x+1)^20 = 1 + 100x + ...

Comment: OK. What you want is: `function(e, n) := ratcoef(e, x, n);`

Answer (score 0):

When defining a function `F(Y)` you want `Y` to be a `x`-dependent input variable for the former, right?

You can directly define the a function `F` of unknown variable `Y` and then input some function as argument.

```
(%i_)   F(Y) := diff(Y(t),t) + Y(t^2);
        F(sin);

(%o_)   F(Y):='diff(Y(t),t,1)+Y(t^2)
(%o_)   sin(t^2)+cos(t)
```

and you are done!

If you try to parse `F(foo(x)):=something + foo(x)` you get

> define: in definition of F, found bad argument foo(x)

There is a more specific way I took from [maxima: use function as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37537422/9106179):
Before defining `F(foo)`, you can tell maxima
"by `foo` I mean `foo(x)`": `depends(foo,x)`.

Then you can define a function with variable `foo`, for example

```
depends(foo,x);
F(foo) := foo(x^2) + foo(x) + diff(foo(x),x) ;
F(sin);
```